# Scala pattern matching for tuple with options still needs unwrapping for the some case

Tags: scala, tuples, pattern-matching

`f(Int)` is an function that returns an `Option[Int]`.

```
def findIntPair(x: Int, y: Int): (Int, Int) = {
    (f(x), f(y)) match {
      case (None, None) || (None, _) || (_, None)  => fail("Unable to find the pair" )
      case (a, b) => (a.get, b.get) // why I still need to unwrap by get
    } 
}
```

Why does the last `case(a, b)` not unwrap them into `Int` but still keep them as `Option[Int]`?

FYI: I'm using intelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Where is the definition of `f`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more about the function f()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pattern match with `Some`:

```
def findIntPair(x: Int, y: Int): (Int, Int) = {
    (f(x), f(y)) match {
      case (None, None) || (None, _) || (_, None)  => fail("Unable to find the pair" )
      case (Some(a), Some(b)) => (a, b)
    } 
}
```

A bit cleaner using a catch-all `case _`:

```
def findIntPair(x: Int, y: Int): (Int, Int) = {
    (f(x), f(y)) match {
      case (Some(a), Some(b)) => (a, b)
      case _  => fail("Unable to find the pair" )
    } 
}
```

Comment: `case _` is equivalent to `case (None, None) || (None, _) || (_, None)` ?

Comment: @SLN: It will match everything, so in this case everything that is not `(Some(a), Some(b))` (since that already have an matching case above). Note that it need to be the last option.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right solution is that you do that by this way:

```
   (f(x), f(y)) match {
     case (None, None) | (None, _) | (_, None)  => fail("Unable to find the pair" )
     case (Some(a), Some(b)) => (a, b) 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of expressing this logic:

```
def findIntPair(x: Int, y: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] =
  for {
    a <- f(x)
    b <- f(y)
  } yield (a,b)
```

This has the advantage that it will not compute `f(y)` if `f(x)` returns `None`. This version returns an `Option` so that the error can be processed later, but you can process it inside the function like this:

```
def findIntPair(x: Int, y: Int): (Int, Int) =
  (
    for {
      a <- f(x)
      b <- f(y)
    } yield  (a, b)
  ).getOrElse(fail("Unable to find the pair"))
```

Note that this assumes that `fail` returns `(Int, Int)`, which is what would be necessary for the code in the question to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because:

```
def findIntPair(x: Int, y: Int): (Int, Int) = {
    (f(x), f(y)) match {
      case (None, None) || (None, _) || (_, None)  => fail("Unable to find the pair" )
      case (a, b) => (a.get, b.get) //here f(x) = a and f(y) = b
    } 
}
```

You want something like this:

```
def findIntPair(x: Int, y: Int): (Int, Int) = {
(f(x), f(y)) match {
  case (None, None) || (None, _) || (_, None)  => fail("Unable to find the pair" )
  case (Some(a), Some(b)) => (a, b)
}
```

}

But thats not the best way to do that i think this is better:

```
def findIntPair(x: Int, y: Int): (Int, Int) = {

    if(f(x).isDefined && f(y).isDefined) (f(x).get,f(y).get)
    else fail("Unable to find the pair" )

}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the first error. You still need to fix your "better" solution so that it returns the results of `f` rather than the input values.